# Syncronizing entries in a table according to a user array in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following situation. The entries in a table come from a list of users for a particular id. That way id 7 has 3 rows for, say, 2, 6, 7 (these three are unique ids for a user data table). To clarify the table looks like this.

```
ID USERID KEYID
```

Where KeyID is auto_inc and is the table's primary key.

These entries come from a multiple select field. So a user might want to delete user 2 and add user 8. So the function that needs to update the table gets the array 8,6,7 for id 7. The quick way I found to do the syncronization is simply to delete every entry in the table for ID 7 and add 3 new entries of the from (ID,USERID) (7,8) (7,6) (7,7).

However I don't know if this is how it's supposed to be. Is there a better way? Also this methods drives the keyid up really fast (for every modification in the table, basically). Is that a problem? I'm an newbie with these things, so please be patient.

Comment: Try to use `UPDATE` rather than `DELETE.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can delete rows selectively like this:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user1 = 7 AND user2 NOT IN (8,6,7)
```

where (8,6,7) is list of pairs (7,6),(7,8),(7,7) , that should be preserved, kept, not deleted, and it will delete all other pairs (7,?)

Your next question may be "Then how to add pairs while not making duplicities?"

You will first need to teach your table what duplicity is. By adding unique key on pair of fields (user1,user2). That would forbid duplicities. Now, when inserting new rows that may be already there, use "INSERT IGNORE" to ignore such exception and simply, continue on.

Comment: That would take care of the deleting, but what about adding only the new entries? (In the example, it would be the 8)